# text below images in a row using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

In a row there are 5 images and text below each image which is responsive.but when coded in bootstrap the images are overlapping when window is resized.

how can we align 5 images horizontally in a row with each having text below.

[image]

Here is model of images and text.Is there any way to make 5 images with text below in it responsive.

Comment: I recently learnt about Bootstrap's [thumbnails](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#thumbnails) which work great for something like this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might need to use `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`:

```
<figure>
  <img />
  <figcaption>Image</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**Snippet**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=IMG" alt="">
        <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=IMG" alt="">
        <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=IMG" alt="">
        <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=IMG" alt="">
        <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=IMG" alt="">
        <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100?text=IMG" alt="">
        <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: when resize this,the images overlaps in small devices.Is there any way to make it responsive in all devices?

Comment: Hi @diya. Yes, you can give `col-sm-2` instead of `col-xs-2`.

Comment: @diya Did it work or not?

Comment: yes.it works.Thank you very much.